# What is the reasonable way to display matrix size?

Tags: matlab, octave

The following conditions are desirable:

- the code should be in one line
- the variable name should be repeated as few times as possible in code (preferably once only), but be present in output
- the output should contain at least leading linebreak (preferrably trailing one too)

Problem code:

```
...
my_variable_name = [1 4];
disp(size(my_varialbe_name));
...
```

Output:

```
1 2
```

Ideal output:

```
...
my_variable_name size: 1 2
...
```

Tried printf, spritf, disp but they fail.

Comment: `fprintf(['Output line1\nmy_variable_name size: ', num2str(size(my_variable_name)),'\nOutput further\n'])`

Comment: What is the code you've tried? `fprintf` should work just fine, you may just be using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to be real fancy, you could write an anonymous function to do this since you can then use `inputname` to infer the name of the input variable.

```
func = @(var)fprintf('\n%s size: %s\n', inputname(1), num2str(size(var)))

x = rand(10, 4);

func(x)
%   x size: 10   4
```

You can also just use `fprintf`

```
fprintf('\n%s size: %s\n', 'myvar', num2str(size(myvar)))
```

Or if you don't want to use `num2str` you can instead use multiple lines

```
fprintf('\n%s size: ', 'myvar')
fprintf('%d ', size(myvar))
fprintf('\n')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Could you also comment on why do people tend to use frprintf here, I thought it is for file output? Also printf works as well.